# How can I create new lines by looping through an object?

Tags: javascript, docx

I am using Electron and the docx module to create dynamically a docx file containing data that was given by users.

I'm currently having issues building a paragraph that consists of lines from an object which I don't know from the start how much data it will have.

The object is like this, currently with only 2 pieces of information.

```
  "opuses": [
    {
      "writer": "Adolphe C. Adam",
      "opus": "Concerto"
    },
    {
      "writer": "Adams John",
      "opus": "Short ride in a fast machine"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried a lot of ways but nothing seems to work.
Thanks a lot!

```
const doc = new Document({
        sections: [{
            properties: {},
            children: [
                new Paragraph({
                    alignment: AlignmentType.JUSTIFIED,
                    children: [
                        new TextRun({
                            text: '// HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO BE THE LINES, CURRENTLY, TWO NEW LINES // ',
                            bold: true,
                            size: 24
                        })
                        // OR HERE AS NEW TextRuns FOR EACH LINE//
                    ],
                }) 
            }]
        })
```

--Update:
the expected outcome would be like I had written:

```
                     . . .
                        new TextRun({
                            text: 'Adolphe C. Adam > Concerto',
                            bold: true,
                            size: 24
                        }),
                        new TextRun({
                            text: 'Adams John > Short ride in a fast machine',
                            bold: true,
                            size: 24
                        }),
                     . . .
```

(I've already tried to make the looped string first and then pass it in the TextRun's text, but the '\n' doesn't work and it's just a long string)

Comment: So the expected result would be "Concerto\nShort ride in a fast machine"?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Thanks to you I clarified my expected result in my post. I need the outcome to be: "Adolphe C. Adam > Concerto \n Adams John > Short ride in a fast machine" (and so on..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you could just do this - run an `array.map()` which will return an array of all opuses.

```
const data = {
  "opuses": [{
      "writer": "Adolphe C. Adam",
      "opus": "Concerto"
    },
    {
      "writer": "Adams John",
      "opus": "Short ride in a fast machine"
    }
  ]
}

const opuses = data.opuses.map(o => (new TextRun({
  text: o.writer + ' > ' + o.opus,
  bold: true,
  size: 24
})));

const doc = new Document({
      sections: [{
          properties: {},
          children: [
            new Paragraph({
              alignment: AlignmentType.JUSTIFIED,
              children: opuses,
            })
          }]
      })
```

```js
const data = {
  "opuses": [{
      "writer": "Adolphe C. Adam",
      "opus": "Concerto"
    },
    {
      "writer": "Adams John",
      "opus": "Short ride in a fast machine"
    }
  ]
}
// this isjust here for testing
class TextRun {
  constructor(obj) {
    this.obj = obj;
  }
}
const opuses = data.opuses.map(o => (new TextRun({
  text: o.writer + ' > ' + o.opus,
  bold: true,
  size: 24
})));

console.log(opuses)
```

Comment: unfortunately no, not only it doesn't render anything after the map function but it also can't be opened showing a warning with this message: "Word encountered an error while opening the file.
Try the following.
* Check the file permissions for the document or drive.
* Make sure there is enough memory and disk space.
* Open the file with the text retrieval converter.
(Test.docx)"

Comment: Hmm. Try this revised answer. I also put a snippet so you can see it's creating the results, though I am not familiar with TextRun

Comment: @GiannisProkopos - how did that revised answer work for you?

Comment: It surely does something towards a solution (it now creates a text saying {object object}), but I think it doesn't solve my issue due to my own lack of actual knowledge on javascript. I'm working on it in my free time and was waiting to thank you as soon as I'd figured it out with your answer. Thank you so much for your interest!